# How to remove spaces in the beginning of lines with Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm working on a project and I need all the lines to be perfectly straight, some lines are fine but many look like this and I need to fix 3,000 of them without having to fix each line individually.

See example below

```
Flying fish flew by the space station.
    The hand sanitizer was actually clear glue.
I received a heavy fine but it failed to crush my spirit.
 He knew it was going to be a bad day when he saw mountain lions roaming the streets.
  Whenever he saw a red flag warning at the beach he grabbed his surfboard.
```

I want it to look like

```
Flying fish flew by the space station.
The hand sanitizer was actually clear glue.
I received a heavy fine but it failed to crush my spirit.
He knew it was going to be a bad day when he saw mountain lions roaming the streets.
Whenever he saw a red flag warning at the beach he grabbed his surfboard.
```

Google, couldn't find results for this

Comment: Use the `m` flag with the following expression `^ +`, replaced by nothing.

Comment: The "m" flag is always on in Notepad++, there is no place to select it in the find and replace dialogues.  The checkbox that optionally allows dot to match newline is usually known as the "s" flag.

Answer (score 3):

Use Menu => **Edit** => **Blank Operations** => **Trim Leading Space**.

Comment: I am really suprised that I could not find a duplicate of this question. Can anyone find a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
^ +
```